# how to create marker on googlemap using database and php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };
    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("maps_xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

        }
      });
    }
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
    function doNothing() {}

  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>1
```

**maps_xml.php**
This is my phpfile which get data from database and create marker dynamically.
But doing so I am geeting map but i able to get any marker on map even around 7 data is inserted.
so kindly help me out on this.

```
<?php
require("config.php");
function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&apos;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost,$username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML('&','&amp;', $row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}
// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
?>
```

Comment: I would first verify the `data` from `downloadUrl()`. Are you getting the expected results?

Comment: Also, consider using [MySQL PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to connect and retrieve from db. For a while deprecated, now mysql_* extensions has been removed in PHP 7. And consider using [htmlentities()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp) instead of own user defined function, `parseToXML()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following that adds small changes:

```
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers";
$results = mysql_query($query);
if (!$results) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\r\n";
echo '<markers>' . "\r\n";
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
    echo "\t<marker ";
    echo 'name="' . parseToXML('&','&amp;', $row['name']) . '" ';
    echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
    echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
    echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
    echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
    echo "/>\r\n";
}
// End XML file
echo "</markers>\r\n";
```

This will add in the proper End of Line and indenting that is proper for XML Formatting. The JS will not read them, but it's good practice. You can then also call the page directly in your browser to test the results, if the XML is correct, you will then need to troubleshoot your JS Code and see why it is not generating the Markers. Check your browsers console (or use tools like FireBug) to look for errors.

**EDIT**

Found that `<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>` appears to be part of the problem. Suggest changeing to Pixel value: `<div id="map" style="width: 1024px; height: 680px;"></div>`.

You are also not setting or updating your Marker Array, in `load()`:

`map.markers = map.markers || [];`

And again in `downloadUrl()`:

`map.markers.push(marker);`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/k5nnsqcL/

Comment: still i got same thing

Comment: Can you post an example of your XML Data?

Comment: Pan Africa Market,"1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA",47.608941,-122.340145,restaurant
Buddha Thai & Bar,"2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA",47.613591,-122.344394,bar
The Melting Pot,"14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA",47.624562,-122.356442,restaurant
Ipanema Grill,"1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA",47.606366,-122.337656,restaurant

Comment: Did some testing. Would advise setting Width and Height to pixel values. I was using 100% and kept getting same result. When I switched to a pixel value, I got the rendered map. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/k5nnsqcL/